# Does mergesort have a best or worst case scenario?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

From my understanding, mergesort works in a way in which it splits an array in different subarrays, until every new array only contains on kind of the content, f.ex. numbers. I have heard that sometimes the array is split until there are new arrays that contain two numbers, but I don't know when that is the case.
These new arrays are then merged and sorted while doing that.

While googling I found that the average, best and worst cases are all n*log(n), I am asking myself if there can be a difference in the time it takes the algorithm to sort.

I don't know if the time it takes the algorithm to sort has anything to do with the amount of numbers that are in an array before they get merged.

I have an implementation of mergesort in java from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/), where I also got the explanation from.

Comment: And you already read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Analysis, including the part *Merge sort's best case takes about half as many iterations as its worst case.*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does.

and its best case takes about half as many iterations as its worst case.

with the best-case happening when the largest element of one sorted sub-list is smaller than the first element of its opposing sub-list, for every merge step that occurs. Only one element from the opposing list is compared, which reduces the number of comparisons in each merge step to N/2.

Comment: The number of moves is always the same, only the number of compares depends on the data being sorted.

Comment: It is worth noting that we hit this whenever there are sorted runs in our data.  Part of the win of Timsort on real-world data is that it looks for these runs (sorted or reversed) and manages to skip even more comparisons for them.

Comment: @btilly - timsort and other variations of natural merge sort reduce the number of passes or levels of recursion, which in turn, reduces the number of moves.